# View on load event handler in Sencha?

Tags: sencha-touch, extjs, sencha-touch-2

In my sencha application home page i have a empty List.  On application stat up I want to fetch the data from database and add it to List store. So is there any listener for view on load. I am using MVC architecture. i tried with controller's "launch" and view's "pained" listeners but no luck. i want something like jqm "pagebeforeshow" where i can do database fetch things before showing page.

```
$("#HomePage").live('pagebeforeshow',function(event, ui){
// fetch data and add to list   
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1) You can override initialize method in your view

```
Ext.define('YourApp.view.YourView', {
    initialize: function () {
       var ctrl = YourApp.app.getController('YourController');
       ctrl.functionYouWantToCall();
}
```

But it's not a good MVC solution...

2) Controller's launch method shoud work. It will be fired when app is loaded. Maybe you forget to add you controller to 'controllers' property of app.js

Answer (score 1):

If you use MVC architecture You can load data in controller action. Look example in sencha touch docs. http://docs.sencha.com/touch/2-0/#!/guide/controllers

```js
 Ext.define('MyApp.controller.Users', {
        extend: 'Ext.app.Controller',

        config: {
            routes: {
                'user/:id': 'showUserById'
            },

            refs: {
                main: '#mainTabPanel'
            }
        },


        // Loads the User then adds a 'userprofile' view to the main TabPanel
        showUserById: function(id) {
            MyApp.model.User.load(id, {
                scope: this,
                success: function(user) {
                    this.getMain().add({
                        xtype: 'userprofile',
                        user: user
                    });
                }
            });
        }
    });
```